# Selecting data from multiple tables that have no foreign keys?

Tags: python, sql, flask, sqlite

I have this current `sqlite3` code in my `python` file:

```
Data = Cursor.execute("""
    SELECT Username, Password
    FROM PatientTable
    WHERE Username = '{}'
""".format(Username))
Data = Data.fetchall()
```

There are multiple tables in the database: `PatientTable`, `DoctorTable`, `ManagerTable`. Each one has attributes of `Username` and `Password` in the second and third column respectively.

**Q:** My current code only selects data from `PatientTable` but I need to select data from all three tables **and** identify which table each item of data came from.

Now, I think I can do this using multiple SQL statements but this seems excessive. I have thought about using `JOIN` but there are no foreign keys - keys relating the databases to each other.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does the (Username,Password) in the 3 tables you mentioned points to the same users? In other words: Does the Patient table contain records that Doctor table contains as well? If the answer in negative there is no way you can join the tables.

Comment: The answer is negative.

Comment: Please clarify your question. I am not sure I understand what is the problem and what are the solutions you are thinking about.

Comment: You answered it - there is no simple way, instead, I can just use three separate SQL statements.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be looking for UNION. You can add a fixed column to each query to distinguish from which table each record in the resultset comes from :

```
SELECT 'PatientTable' source_table, Username, Password 
FROM PatientTable 
WHERE Username = '{}'
UNION ALL SELECT 'DoctorTable' , Username, Password 
FROM DoctorTable 
WHERE Username = '{}'
UNION ALL SELECT 'ManagerTable', Username, Password 
FROM ManagerTable 
WHERE Username = '{}'
```